# How to silence all the Gradle outputs except if there are errors?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I need to **maintain the output of the script exactly the same** as if it was run with `java app.Main`, adding **no extra output** and preserving the `stdout` and `stderr` exactly the same.

Is there a way to do that with gradle? Turn this:

```
$ gradle run

> Task :run
Hello World

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
$
```

into this

```
$ gradle run
Hello World
```

It **should show errors** though if it can't compile and run the project.

The project is Kotlin if that matters.

P.S.

If that's not possible, what would be the best way to achieve something like that?

```
gradle build && java app.Main
```

Couple of questions

- Is `gradle build` fast? I would like to have fastest incremental compile option so it would compile as fast as possible.
- How to pass **class paths** from gradle into `java app.Main`?
- How to suppress info and warn output from `gradle build` but leave the errors?

Comment: (2) See [`System#getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()); (3) See [Setting log level](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#setting_log_level)

Comment: (1) See [Incremental Compilation (Kotlin)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#incremental-compilation) and/or [Incremental Java compilation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:incremental_compile).

Comment: Hi @Slaw. Is it possible to set `--quiet` flag inside build.gradle?

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili Not that I know of off the top of my head. I suspect that by the time the build file is executed it's too late to set the logging level and get the exact same behavior as if using `--quiet`. It might even be too late by the time the settings file is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Run with no warning mode:

```
gradle --warning-mode none run
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to gradle.properties

`org.gradle.logging.level=quiet`